# Could "Context.User" be a null?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

In my MasterPage code-behind I try to get UserID of the authenticated (if it has) one:

```
public Guid CurrentUserID
    {
        get
        {
            Guid userID = new Guid();
            if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(Context.User.Identity.Name);
                userID = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
            }
            return userID;
        }
    }
```

Once the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" appeared. I suspect the problem is in the case Context.User=null. Could it be the reason?

Comment: Did you attach a debugger and confirm your suspicion? Maybe `Identity` is null.

Comment: Unfortunately the error was written by our own logwriter on published site and only once. In the debug-mode I have never reached the error

Comment: Do you have implemented your own membership provider?

Comment: No, just use standard AspNetSqlMembershipProvider

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the user was deleted by the db while he was authenticated, so `Membership.GetUser` returned `null` and `user.ProviderUserKey` has thrown `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Yep, it seems to be logic but it's not the case. Probably cookie file was deleted. Could it be the reason?

Comment: if cookie is deleted the user is no more authenticated.